# Instagram anonymous?

Tags: instagram

If I have viewed an Instagram account (found on a Google search) could the owner of the account see that I have viewed it (pics and videos etc) if I was logged into Google at the time? Would they be able to see my name as having accessed their account?

Answer (score 2):

Officially answer is **No**. There’s no way to know if someone has searched for them or visited their profile on Instagram. Just as Facebook doesn't report who has viewed your profile, Instagram doesn't either.

**Note:** There are so many third party apps who claim that by using those app(s) you can get the list of people who have searched or visited your profile (or photos, videos), but I am not sure how true they are (I have never used any). There are huge chances that they are spam.